# parse log file - using java and plot graph

Tags: java, parsing, graph, logging

I am writing a log analyzer program which is supposed to plot a graph on search string against time after parsing log file(s). I am currently clueless about how would I parse and store the log file so that it could be processed to create multiple outputs, now I am parsing the entire log file all the time and process to do this – any suggestions?

Comment: Just for a moment: Imagine you are someone else and reread your question. Did you yourself understand what you aim for with this question? What kind of log. What produces the log? And many more questions arise on my side when reading your question

Comment: i thought that was simple. let me try- i get huge log files with system out of our internal application which would contain many exception traces. now, I need to write a program to plot a graph with the number of exceptions in 'Y' axis and time in 'x' axis based on the occurance of the search string in the file.
Additionally, user should be able to give a search string and the graph should be plotted similarly. am seeking suggestion on, if I should keep the file as such and parse the file every time or generate the data for the graph and store it in some form.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer) along with [Batch processing](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/BatchProcessing) to process log files. Depending on scenario, you could create charts with [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or insert log events to database (mysql or [MongoDB](http://blog.aparnachaudhary.net/2012/04/09/archive-log-files-using-spring-data-mongodb/))

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

Use either Apache Chainsaw - http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html - or Lilith - http://lilith.huxhorn.de/ - to parse and view your log files.

You can preprocess your logfiles easily with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, I would look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for drawing graphs once you've parsed the log.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to write a file for each search string. In the file write each timestamp where the string occurs. Then process these files to create a list of search strings and counts. You can then process these files to produce the graphs you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) suite to do this, its open source java with good backing and usage.

1. Use Pentaho Kettle to [bulk load into MySql](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Bulkload+into+MySQL)
2. Use [Report Designer](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Report+Designer) to pull out the stats into a pretty picture